# Android Studio - When uploading project to Google version control, I get an error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform

I want to upload my project to Google Cloud, using Android Studio's version control. But, I get a weird error:

```
Error running git
```

I don't understand. I'm not even running Git; I want Google Cloud. This is weird. I go to VCS -> *Import to version control* -> *Upload Project to Google Cloud*.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to install `Git`. This solved my problem.